# Application of Darboux's theorem to magnetic field line flows

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, plasma-physics

In [this famous paper by Cary and Littlejohn](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003491683903135) on noncanonical Hamiltonian mechanics and its application to magnetic field line flow, they claim that as a result of [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem#Statement_and_first_consequences), it is always possible to cast the vector potential one form $\mathbf{A}\cdot d\mathbf{x} = A_idx^i$ in canonical form $p\,dq - \mathcal{H}(p,q,t)\,dt$. I can see that this is possible by making a gauge choice that eliminates one of the terms from the vector potential one form, but how is this a corollary of Darboux's theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Given a $1$-form 
$$A~=~\sum_{I=1}^n A_I \mathrm{d}x^I \tag{1}$$ of constant rank in an odd-dimensional manifold $M$,
it follows from the [Darboux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem) that
there exists a local coordinate system
$$(\underbrace{q^1, \ldots, q^r}_{\text{positions}} ;\underbrace{p_1,\ldots, p_r}_{\text{momenta}}; \underbrace{c^1, \ldots, c^{n-1-2r}}_{\text{Casimirs}};\underbrace{t}_{\text{time}})\tag{2} $$
in a neighborhood $U\subseteq M$ such that the $1$-form $A$ is of the form
$$A|_U ~=~ \sum_{i=1}^r p_i \mathrm{d}q^i -H \mathrm{d}t,\tag{3} $$
where $H$ is a constant (either $0$ or $-1$).